# Find k out of n subset with maximal area

Tags: c, algorithm, dynamic-programming, bottom-up

I have `n` points and have to find the maximum united area between `k` points (`k <= n`). So, its the sum of those points area minus the common area between them.

[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qgFE.png)

Suppose we have `n=4, k=2`. As illustrated in the image above, the areas are calculated from each point to the origin and, the final area is the sum of the B area with the D are (only counting the area of their intersection once). No point is dominated

I have implemented a bottom-up dynamic programming algorithm, but it has an error somewhere. Here is the code, that prints out the best result:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct point {
    double x, y;
} point;
struct point *point_ptr;

int n, k;
point points_array[1201];
point result_points[1201];

void qsort(void *base, size_t nitems, size_t size,
           int (*compar)(const void *, const void *));

int cmpfunc(const void *a, const void *b) {
    point *order_a = (point *)a;
    point *order_b = (point *)b;
    if (order_a->x > order_b->x) {
        return 1;
    }
    return -1;
}

double max(double a, double b) {
    if (a > b) {
        return a;
    }
    return b;
}

double getSingleArea(point p) {
    return p.x * p.y;
}

double getCommonAreaX(point biggest_x, point new_point) {
    double new_x;
    new_x = new_point.x - biggest_x.x;
    return new_x * new_point.y;
}

double algo() {
    double T[k][n], value;
    int i, j, d;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        T[0][i] = getSingleArea(points_array[i]);
    }
    for (j = 0; j < k; j++) {
        T[j][0] = getSingleArea(points_array[0]);
    }
    for (i = 1; i < k; i++) {
        for (j = 1; j < n; j++) {
            for (d = 0; d < j; d++) {
                value = getCommonAreaX(points_array[j - 1], points_array[j]);
                T[i][j] = max(T[i - 1][j], value + T[i - 1][d]);
            }
        }
    }
    return T[k - 1][n - 1];
}

void read_input() {
    int i;
    fscanf(stdin, "%d %d\n", &n, &k);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        fscanf(stdin, "%lf %lf\n", &points_array[i].x, &points_array[i].y);
    }
}

int main() {
    read_input();
    qsort(points_array, n, sizeof(point), cmpfunc);
    printf("%.12lf\n", algo());
    return 0;
}
```

with the input:

```
5 3
0.376508963445 0.437693410334
0.948798695015 0.352125307881
0.176318878234 0.493630156084
0.029394902328 0.951299438575
0.235041868262 0.438197791997
```

where the first number equals `n`, the second `k` and the following lines the `x` and `y` coordinates of every point respectively, the result should be: `0.381410589193`,

whereas mine is `0.366431740966`. So I am missing a point?

Comment: I'm sure this is just me, but when you write "[..] its the sum of those points area minus the common area between them", I don't know what you mean exactly. A point does not generally have an area. If you could graph this for me with a simple example figure, I'm sure the question immediately becomes a lot clearer!

Comment: @N.Wouda I can see how it would be confusing, did not explain very well. Added an image for clarification and updated what I meant

Comment: @Michael.leaves77 why is the final area just the union of B and D but ignoring A and C?

Comment: @FelixG Because even though we have 4 points (`n`) we have to find the maximum area only using `k` points. In this case `k` is 2.

Comment: @Michael.leaves77 Okay, got it. So you need to find the combination of `k` areas which will yield the maximum value

Comment: For any set of `k` points, the effective area will be the sum of the 1-point areas, minus the sum of the 2-points intersections, plus the sum of the 3-points intersections, minus the sum of the 4-point intersections, etc.

Comment: Perhaps the way to go is the [Inclusion–exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).

Comment: @WeatherVane how would that answer the problem described above?

Comment: @WeatherVane Yes, that's exactly what my description implements.

Comment: @Michael.leaves77 That gives you the area for any subset of `k` points.  You would then examine all subsets of `k` points, calculate the area for each, and take the maximum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a neat little problem, thanks for posting! In the remainder, I'm going to assume no point is *dominated*, that is, there are no points `c` such that there exists a point `d` with `c.x < d.x` and `c.y < d.y`. If there are, then it is never optimal to use `c` (why?), so we can safely ignore any dominated points. None of your example points are dominated.

Your problem exhibits optimal substructure: once we have decided which item is to be included in the first iteration, we have the same problem again with `k - 1`, and `n - 1` (we remove the selected item from the set of allowed points). Of course the pay-off depends on the set we choose - we do not want to count areas twice.

I propose we pre-sort all point by their x-value, in increasing order. This ensures the value of a selection of points can be computed as piece-wise areas. I'll illustrate with an example: suppose we have three points, `(x1, y1), ..., (x3, y3)` with values `(2, 3), (3, 1), (4, .5)`. Then the total area covered by these points is `(4 - 3) * .5 + (3 - 2) * 1 + (2 - 0) * 3`. I hope it makes sense in a graph:

[image: figure]

By our assumption that there are no dominated points, we will always have such a weakly decreasing figure. Thus, pre-sorting solves the entire problem of "counting areas twice"!

Let us turn this into a dynamic programming algorithm. Consider a set of `n` points, labelled `{p_1, p_2, ..., p_n}`. Let `d[k][m]` be the maximum area of a subset of size `k + 1` where the `(k + 1)`-th point in the subset is point `p_m`. Clearly, `m` cannot be chosen as the `(k + 1)`-th point if `m < k + 1`, since then we would have a subset of size less than `k + 1`, which is never optimal. We have the following recursion,

```
d[k][m] = max {d[k - 1][l] + (p_m.x - p_l.x) * p_m.y, for all k <= l < m}.
```

The initial cases where `k = 1` are the rectangular areas of each point. The initial cases together with the updating equation suffice to solve the problem.  I estimate the following code as `O(n^2 * k)`. The term squared in `n` can probably be lowered as well, as we have an ordered collection and might be able to apply a binary search to find the best subset in `log n` time, reducing `n^2` to `n log n`. I leave this to you.

In the code, I have re-used my notation above where possible. It is a bit terse, but hopefully clear with the explanation given.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct point
{
    double x;
    double y;
} point_t;


double maxAreaSubset(point_t const *points, size_t numPoints, size_t subsetSize)
{
    // This should probably be heap allocated in your program.
    double d[subsetSize][numPoints];

    for (size_t m = 0; m != numPoints; ++m)
        d[0][m] = points[m].x * points[m].y;

    for (size_t k = 1; k != subsetSize; ++k)
        for (size_t m = k; m != numPoints; ++m)
            for (size_t l = k - 1; l != m; ++l)
            {
                point_t const curr = points[m];
                point_t const prev = points[l];

                double const area = d[k - 1][l] + (curr.x - prev.x) * curr.y;

                if (area > d[k][m])  // is a better subset
                    d[k][m] = area;
            }

    // The maximum area subset is now one of the subsets on the last row.
    double result = 0.;

    for (size_t m = subsetSize; m != numPoints; ++m)
        if (d[subsetSize - 1][m] > result)
            result = d[subsetSize - 1][m];

    return result;
}

int main()
{
    // I assume these are entered in sorted order, as explained in the answer.
    point_t const points[5] = {
            {0.029394902328, 0.951299438575},
            {0.176318878234, 0.493630156084},
            {0.235041868262, 0.438197791997},
            {0.376508963445, 0.437693410334},
            {0.948798695015, 0.352125307881},
    };

    printf("%f\n", maxAreaSubset(points, 5, 3));
}
```

Using the example data you've provided, I find an optimal result of `0.381411`, as desired.

Comment: I wasn't going to say anything because you did plenty, but I am having a hard time understanding this correctly. Guess I should reopen a python book

Comment: @Michael.leaves77 I might post a C implementation tomorrow.  Should not be too hard.  The recursions are the important part, and I believe those are correct. I hope you can implement those yourself using the explanation I've given.

Comment: I don't see why we need such a complex area calculation. My routine seems in line with the OP's intention, I think, and calculates the area in `O(1)` per iteration, no caching needed. `O(n^2 * k)` naive implementation.

Comment: @גלעדברקן good call! I was tracking subsets, but that's more complex than required. I've now updated it to just track the area tableau, which dispenses the need for recalculating. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, you and I both use the same method to calculate the area, as well as the overall concept, but my code seems to be returning a correct result. Perhaps reviewing it can help you find a discrepancy.

JavaScript code:

```js
function f(pts, k){
  // Sort the points by x
  pts.sort(([a1, b1], [a2, b2]) => a1 - a2);

  const n = pts.length;
  let best = 0;
  
  // m[k][j] represents the optimal
  // value if the jth point is chosen
  // as rightmost for k points
  let m = new Array(k + 1);
  
  // Initialise m
  for (let i=1; i<=k; i++)
    m[i] = new Array(n);
  for (let i=0; i<n; i++)
    m[1][i] = pts[i][0] * pts[i][1];
    
  // Build the table
  for (let i=2; i<=k; i++){
    for (let j=i-1; j<n; j++){
      m[i][j] = 0;
      for (let jj=j-1; jj>=i-2; jj--){
        const area = (pts[j][0] - pts[jj][0]) * pts[j][1];
        m[i][j] = Math.max(m[i][j], area + m[i-1][jj]);
      }
      best = Math.max(best, m[i][j]);
    }
  }

  return best;
}

var pts = [
  [0.376508963445, 0.437693410334],
  [0.948798695015, 0.352125307881],
  [0.176318878234, 0.493630156084],
  [0.029394902328, 0.951299438575],
  [0.235041868262, 0.438197791997]
];

var k = 3;

console.log(f(pts, k));
```